# AMD Opteron BSOD - A clock interrupt was not received on a secondary processor within the allocation time interval

Tags: bsod, 64-bit

On one of our servers we got an -for me new- BSOD with the error message:
"A clock interrupt  was not received on a secondary processor within the allocation time interval"

The server's specs:
HP XW9400
2x Dual-Core AMD Opeteron 2224 SE 3,20Ghz (4CPUs)
16GB HP ECC RAM
Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise 64bit
Nvidia Quadro 4xxx graphics (?)

Sounds familiar to someone ?

Thanks in advance

[image: BSOD]

Comment: @laurens: check to make sure you are on all the latest bios/firmware levels for your computer - but I would say this is signaling a failing processor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(coming back to an old question)
At that moment, I upgraded the bios and it was solved! (also vacuumed the coolers for the occasion)

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem with an older DualCore AMD whose CPU cooler didn't work.